# Android : OnViewCreated called but fragment not visible

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-2.2-froyo, dynamic-ui

So,it is me again, further working  on my dynamic ui and it seems as if I have almost reached a point, where the success-effect should come. But now my steps are smaller I move slowly towarda a milestone.

We are still talking about a completely dynamicaly created ui based on fragmentManager and fragments, which for themselves are populated with some subelements like textviews, buttons, table columns ,whatever.

According to my oo design, I have a controller class, which is the one and only instance member of my fragment activity.

The constructor of **controller gets activity reference of fragment activity passed as argument** , in order to create **FragmentManager and hold it globally.**

The controller instantiates an object of a custom class, which is derived from fragment.

The overloaded constructor is called correctly, calling base ctor and doing some other stuff.

Then I add the object into the fragment manager which was created in the ctor of the controller with the help of the passed activity by beginning a transaction and committing it.

The controller is left, the flow returns to mainactivity, where I issue setcontentview at the end.

However, the onCreateView is executed, oViewCreated gets executed, where I define an layout of my and a backcolor and one testbutton. Then I place all stuf nicely onto the ui.
As tested with a fragment derivate in the controller class, this worked.
But now, in the more or less real situation I do not see the fragment.
After committing in cotroller I also issue detach and attach again to force redrawing.

I suppose, somewhere I will have to pass atomic references. Could this be possible ?

THX in advance.

Edit: Solved.

Delete this?

Comment: Sorry, Solved.
One must implement override of onViewCreate in order to be processed first and then onViewCreated will also be processed. Who knows, why.

Comment: But I still do not see my "relatively deeply in my oo hierarchy inserted" fragment on the screen.
Could it be wrong returning container.getRootView by onCreateView ?
Because at that time I have no other view.

Comment: Should I in order to create a new one which is called "Why Is still do not see my fragment on the screen" ?
Would be flooding, I suppose... so why not sticking to this one ?

Comment: There are four or 5 snippets.
Still provide ?

Comment: ok, was just making sure, You are willing to check 5 snippets. They will be added to my question soon.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question ( perhaps someone else also had similar problems ) and would like to know, whether my approach is ok:

the overridden eventhandler onCreateView simply must return new View(getActivity());